# Induction: $\sum_{k\mathop=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}2$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n k^3 = \left(\sum_{k=1}^n k\right)^2$

Tags: induction

> Prove by induction that for all $n \in \Bbb N$
>   $$\sum_{k\mathop=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}2 \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{k\mathop=1}^n k^3 = \left(\sum_{k\mathop=1}^n k\right)^2$$

I have proved the first part but can anyone show me how to solve the second part?

Thanks.

Comment: Replace the right-hand side according to the first identity and act as usual

Comment: Mind showing me how to do it? THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to prove that $$1^3+2^3+...+n^3=\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}.$$
For $n=1$ it's obvious and for the proof of
$$1^3+2^3+...+n^3+(n+1)^3=\frac{(n+1)^2(n+2)^2}{4}$$
it's enough to prove that
$$\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}+(n+1)^3=\frac{(n+1)^2(n+2)^2}{4},$$
which is obvious.

Comment: thanks so much. Im new to this page how do i vote?

Comment: @arcadeboy Click up arrow. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> **Theorem**. $$ \sum_{k = 1}^n k^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} $$

*Proof*: (by Induction). Let $P_n$ be the proposition:
$$P_n: \qquad \sum_{k = 1}^n k^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} $$

**Base Case**:
$$ \sum_{k = 1}^1 k^3 = 1^3 = 1 $$
$$ \frac{1^2(1+1)^2}{4} = \frac{1\cdot4}{4} = 1 $$
Therefore $P_1$ holds.

**Inductive Step**: Assume, for the sake of induction, $P_m$, for some arbitrary $m$. Then:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k = 1}^m k^3 &= \frac{m^2(m+1)^2}{4} \\
\sum_{k = 1}^m k^3 + (m+1)^3 &= \frac{m^2(m+1)^2}{4} + (m+1)^3 \\
\sum_{k = 1}^{m+1} k^3 &= (m+1)^2 \left[ \frac{m^2}{4} + (m+1) \right] \\
&= (m+1)^2 \cdot \frac{m^2 + 4m + 4}{4} \\
&=  \frac{(m+1)^2(m+2)^2}{4} \\
\end{align*}
Therefore, $P_m \implies P_{m+1}$.

**Conclusion**: We have shown:
$$ P_1 \wedge (P_m \implies P_{m+1})$$
By mathematical induction, we have that $P_n$ holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I love you working. could you please look at my other question ? thank you

Comment: I think given this example of mathematical induction, you should be able to write a proof by mathematical induction for your other question. It would be good practice for you.

Comment: How would you do the LHS I managed to get (k + 1) (( k + 1 )  + 1) / 2