# Prove by induction $\sum_{k=1}^n k^3 =( \sum_{k=1}^n k )^2 $

Tags: induction

Can anyone show me how to prove this example by induction? I can't figure it out. $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^3 =\left( \sum_{k=1}^n k \right)^2  $$

Comment: what you've tried?

Comment: I have tried writing the left side as $ \frac{n^2 (n+1)^2}{4}$

Comment: Duplicate of [MSE question 62171](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/62171). "Proving 1^3+2^3+...+n^3=(n(n+1)/2)^2 using induction" and [MSE question 2281596](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2281596).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** You can first pose $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n k $ and apply the identity $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ with $S_{n+1}^2 = (S_n + (n+1))^2$. Using the recurrence hypothesis, you will find the result.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k^3$ and $v_n=(\sum_{k=1}^n k)^2$. You have to prove $u_n=v_n$ for all $n\ge1$. The base case is clear. Now,
$$u_{n+1}=u_n+(n+1)^3$$
and
$$v_{n+1}=v_n^2+2(n+1)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k\right) + \left(\sum_{k=1}^n k\right)^2$$
So all you have to do is compare those two induction steps.

Comment: Why isn't your first equation $$u_{n+1}=u_n+(n+1)^3?$$. That's confused me

Comment: @RhysHughes You are right, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Inductive step: 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^3=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k\right)^2+(n+1)^3=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2+(n+1)^3=(n+1)^2\left(\frac{n^2}{4}+n+1\right)=\\
\frac{(n+1)^2(n+2)^2}{4}=\left(\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}\right)^2=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k\right)^2$$